# How to convert string with any format To DateTime

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, datatable

I have a `DateTime` as `string` with **different formats** in Excel. I want to *convert* the `string` format to `DateTime` using c#. but I am getting the following exception:

> string was not recognized as valid date time.

```
DateTimeOffset.Parse("09/20/2019 17:25:59");
```

**Expected:**

> 09/20/2019 17:25:59

**Actual:**

> System.FormatException

Comment: You can do "any" format, you need to specify it exactly, though you can specify [multiple formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTimeOffset_ParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_).

Comment: Do you know the format of each value in advance?

Comment: Use `ParseExact` with the appropriate format. Or pass the `CultureInfo` object that corresponds to this ofrmat as the second parameter, eg `Parse("..",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))`

Comment: What do the `Excel` and `datatable` tags have to do with this question? Excel stores dates natively, which means they can be read as `DateTime` directly. What is the *actual* question?

Comment: I copy pasted your code and didn't find any issues. Appears to be that your PC date format might be different that what you are trying to parse. In this case you should use ParseExact

Comment: What date does `2/1/2019` represent? Feb. 1st or Jan 2nd?

Comment: `Parse` always seems to cause headaches for *somebody somewhere* down the line. I pretty much use `ParseExact` exclusively.

Comment: I dont know the exact format

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` [Doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var dateThatDesired = DateTime.ParseExact("09/20/2019 17:25:59","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you have limited numbers of formats in the excel table you can test them with `DateTime.TryParseExact()` and if return with a success you can use the parsed dateTime which you will get with `out` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no *universal format*, since date representations are *ambiguous*, a classical example is

```
 01/02/03 == 2 Jan 2003 (USA)  
 01/02/03 == 1 Feb 2003 (Russia) 
 01/02/03 == 3 Feb 2001 (China)
```

If you have a *collection* of expected formats, you can try `ParseExact`, e.g.

```
 string[] possibleFormats = new[] {
   "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss",   // USA
   "dd'.'MM'.'yyyy HH:mm:ss",   // Russia
   "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH:mm:ss",   // China
   "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH:mm:ss", // ISO 8601
 };

 string value = @"09/20/2019 17:25:59";

 DateTimeOffset result = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
   value, 
   possibleFormats, 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
   DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```